# Put paragraph to h2 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

First: I am new to jQuery. I try put a paragraph tag into a h2 tag using jQuery. Website is built on a CMS so the HTML is generated by the CMS. But I can give you a few HTML code and a short jQuery code what I tried before:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>Title goes here</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').find('h1').replaceWith(function(){
        return '<h2>' + $(this).text() + '</h2>';
    });
    $('<p></p>').prependTo('h2');
});
```

The jQuery code does this with my HTML code (which is not too bad, it just has to be optimized):

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>
    <p></p>
    Title goes here
    </h2>
</div>
```

My problem now is, I'd like to get the "Title goes here" into the `p` tag. Is there a jQuery function to do this or am I completely wrong? I already had a look at the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) but I didn't find anything what could help me. Any suggestions?

Cheers

PS: Here is a fiddle: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5apmU/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy: you select the contents of the `h2` with `contents` and then wrap them all in a `p` with `wrapAll`. You can combine this with the function syntax of `replaceWith` to do this all in one line.

```
$('h1').replaceWith(function(this) {
    return $(this).contents().wrapAll('<h2/>').wrapAll('<p/>').closest('h2');
});
```

A better question would be *why* you want to do this. `h2` elements may not contain `p` elements.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5apmU/1/)

Comment: Nice, thank you :) If I did `.wrapAll` twice, it creates two `p` tags. A paragraph in a paragraph. I've just removed `.wrapAll('<p/>')`. But I got one more question: Why is the `/` at the end of `<h2>`? Normally it looks like `</h2>`

Comment: @Roman `<p/>` is an empty `p` element, equivalent to `<p></p>`. You need to realise that you are working with the DOM, not with HTML. You don't wrap elements in HTML, but in DOM elements. Check the fiddle to see it in action: it only wraps the content in one `p` element.

Comment: Ah okay. Maybe I should have a closer look to DOM elements. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is **invalid** HTML, and hence, appending the tags to the string won't work as browser will parse those tags in a valid way, so it will close the `p` tag, and then it will render the `h1` tag.

[image]

Copy paste the code below over [here](http://validator.w3.org/check) on the *Validate By Direct Input* tab and check it out yourself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>This is invalid</p></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Hmm, but the CMS (wordpress) generate automatically a `p` in a `h1`. Why is this if it is invalid?

Comment: @Roman Sorry, I don't use Open Source CMS... but this is one of the good reason why to ignore them :)

Comment: Haha :) Now I am really confused why wordpress is doing this :o

Comment: @Roman hehe, I hate wordpress, joomla, etc so I have my own CMS :) simple and on the point

Comment: Okay, it's cool to have an own, personal CMS :) Normally wordpress is doing a really good job. Nothing and nobody is perfect :P

Comment: @Roman Yea, but it's open source, so hackers knows the vulnerabilities loop holes etc so I consider building my own :) but yes, different people have different views over this :)

Comment: That’s all very true and relevant, but not an answer to the question. It is possible (though rarely a good idea) to create, in the DOM, an HTML document that violates HTML specifications, e.g. by simply putting a `p` child in an `h2` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is jquery clone(). Clone the required paragraph and then append it to the required dom element. http://api.jquery.com/clone/